# Adding SQL source code to comments

Tags: comments

I was trying to add the following SQL source code to a comment:

```
DELETE a,b,c FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON (a.ID = b.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON (a.ID = c.post_id)
WHERE a.post_type = 'revision'
```

and tried this approaches:

- posted by using the backoffice
- used [Source Code in Comments Plugin](http://zenverse.net/source-codes-in-comments-plugin/) with the code brackets
- and the `<code>` tags
- through Postable (www.elliotswan.com/postable) first

It always redirect to the homepage.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can post that text in a comment just fine "as is", no wrapping HTML..

Comment: me too; can you post a link to the page on which this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry guys!

The problem was with the configurations in the WordPress plugin [Firewall 2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-firewall-2/)...it was blocking the submission.

Thanks ayway.

Comment: I just wanted to comment that this might be caused by some "security" plugin.

Comment: that's a pretty bad plugin if it resorts to such actions to block spam or hack attempts...